# Batch file to search multiple subdirectories for file/folder, if found, copy that subdirectory to another location

Tags: batch-file, copy, robocopy

Firstly, I apologize for the lack of preliminary code. I am very novice at this stuff. I have spent a few hours Googling and tried a few different things however, nothing is working out.

I didn't think there was much point copy pasting something here, which may be on completely the wrong track.

If, despite that, you're interested in my query, please read on.

I want to search all sub-folders under a specific folder for another folder/file/file extension and if that file/folder exists, copy the folder to another location. The Folder structure, up to the point where the file or folder is found would need to be intact (with only the folders necessary to get to that folder).

Example folder structure:

```
X:\
+---Folder123
|   +---------FolderA
|   |         +-------Folder!
|   |         +-------Folder@
|   |         \-------Folder#
+---Folder456
|   +---------FolderA
|   |         +-------Folder!
|   |         +-------Folder$
|   |         \-------Folder#
\---Folder789
    \---------FolderA
              +-------Folder!
              +-------Folder@
              \-------Folder%
```

Let's say I wanted to search Drive `X:` for every instance of `Folder@` and then copy that folder (and contents) to a new location with the necessary folders to get to `Folder@`.

So I would end up with something like:

Drive2:

> Folder123/FolderA/Folder@
>   Folder789/FolderA/Folder@

If the in-between folders were excluded and I just ended up with:

> Folder123/Folder@
>   Folder789/Folder@

This would suffice.

Is something like this possible?
Any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: You pre-apology makes no difference to how this site works. You say you've done research  and tried some things which didn't work. Those things are what we want to see, it shows us at least that you're not asking us to do your work for you while you make no effort whatsoever.

Comment: start with `dir /s /ad /b Folder@`. Read output of `dir /?` for explanation of switches. If that looks good, put a `for /f` around (read output of `for /?`) to execute a command (`copy /?`) for each of the returned paths. Show your code, when you get stuck.

Comment: @Stephan
Thank you for the tips. I think I have working code.
EDIT: I tried to add the code to this post and then to the OP but I either cannot format it or the editor tells me it's not formatted corrected. I give up. Posting on this site is more difficult than coding, itself.
Anyway, thank you.

Compo
I did not come here expecting someone would spend hours working on it, until it was done.
After spending hours and getting nowhere, I posted here thinking someone may just know how to do it and may be able to whip up the code in a couple of minutes.

Comment: Click on the word `edit` below the question. Paste the code into the editbox. Mark it and press the `{}` button above the editbox to format it as code. `For` syntax is horrible, when you are not used to it (and even for a regular user there are enough quirks and traps) and it's no shame to ask for help with it.